# How to refresh bookmarks with Firefox extension API

Tags: javascript, api, firefox

I am writing a Firefox extension that automatically sorts bookmarks.

Everything works fine, except one thing:

The bookmarks are not refreshing.

The bookmarks get sorted, but Firefox don't refresh the bookmark list.

I am using a [bookmark observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsINavBookmarksService#addObserver%28%29) to know when a bookmark is added.

In the [onItemAdded() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsINavBookmarkObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsINavBookmarkObserver#onItemAdded%28%29), I call my sorting function. The folder gets sorted, but Firefox does not show it. If I close Firefox and reopen it, the folder is sorted. I can also see it sorted if I click on "Show all bookmarks" and click on the folder.

I added a button in my extension and when I click on it, the bookmarks get sorted without any problem. This problem comes when the bookmarks are sorted right after a bookmark insert or move.

By the way, my extension also sort bookmarks when the user moves a bookmark.
The bookmarks get refreshed if I move a bookmark within the same folder.
But they didn't get refreshed if I move a bookmark in another folder.

So I looking for a way to refresh the Firefox bookmarks to show the sorted folder at the right time.

Is there a way of doing that?
If not, what do you propose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using setTimeout() so that the script wait one second before sorting.
This works fine and the bookmarks get sorted and refreshed.